# Example of functions of particular type?

Tags: number-theory, functions

Is it possible that an arithmetic function $f$ which satisfies $$\sum_{n \leq x}f(n)=O(x^\alpha)$$ where $\alpha < 1$ and $$\sum_{n \leq x}\dfrac{f(n)}{n}=O(x^\beta)$$ where $\beta>1$. Can you give an example of such a function. Is there any theory for such functions?

Comment: What about $f(n) = 0$?  Also it seems like the second condition always follows from the first, since $\beta \gt \alpha$ and the second sum grows more slowly.  Do you mean $\Theta$ instead of $O$?

Comment: Actually that is what my question is...whether the second sum always grow more slowly than the first sum. I would like to have non trivial example.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $F(x)=\sum_{n\le x} f(n)$ and $G(x) = \sum_{n\le x} \frac{f(n)}n$, then partial summation gives the identity
$$
G(x) = \frac{F(x)}x + \int_1^x \frac{F(t)}{t^2} \,dt.
$$
(You can verify this by plugging in the definition of $F(x)$ on the right-hand side.) If you are assuming that $F(x)=O(x^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha<1$, then the right-hand side is actually *bounded* (indeed, converges to the constant $\int_1^\infty \frac{F(t)}{t^2} \,dt$) as $x$ tends to infinity. In particular, there's no way that $G(x)$ will have larger order than $F(x)$ here.